# How to run a jar with all it's dependecies downloaded from maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run an app downloaded from maven. When i run it through cmd i get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jmrtd-0.7.36.jar

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jmrtd-0.7.36.jar
```

Double clicking and open it directly but it has dependencies and don't know how to put it together

Comment: Well `jmrtd-0.7.36.jar` is clearly not a classname, so of course it can't find it.

Comment: "*When i run it through cmd*" Using what command?

Comment: Never heard of this thing, but from a little research it seems this is not an application. It's a library; you can't run it. It's a collection of classes designed to be used to build applications.

Comment: Sounds like you wrote `java jmrtd-0.7.36.jar` when you should have written `java -jar jmrtd-0.7.36.jar`.

Comment: @Michael is right. That's not an app. It's an API

Comment: Thanks guys, so what is needed to make it run?

Comment: It won't ever run. It's not meant to. It's a *library*, an API. You need to understand what those words mean